# iOS Dev: video App - size limit

Tags: xcode, appstore-approval

I know this has probably been answered before but I couldn't find an answer

We have a client that is currently selling video DVDs with dance classes. He wants to convert it to an App for obvious reasons.

The DVD has 90 minutes of video (divided in 8 chapters) so we estimated that it would be around 1.6GB of size. I'd like to know best practices for this.

We would like to download the 8 videos embedded in the App to avoid the user having to download chapters once they open the App (and to avoid hosting fees).

We are targeting iOS 6 because most of his customers have the latests iOS devices. We don't want to stream the video, it should play locally for different reasons.

Is 1.6GB too much for an App? Any suggestions for this scenario?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

(iOS only) App Size Tips

iOS apps can be as large as 2 GB, but consider download times when determining your app’s size. Minimize the file’s size as much as possible, keeping in mind that there is a 50 MB limit for over-the-air downloads.

Answer (score 1):

Too big, I think. Personally I would make the chapters downloadable and perhaps offer a 'download all' option for anyone who wants to get all the videos in one hit.

Making it modular (i.e. app and content separate) should also make it easier to add content or update the app when required.

Answer (score 0):

Why not include  the first chapter and build a download option for the rest of them? Best of both worlds.
Don't forget you can re-encode the video to reduce the size. If its a DVD rip you'll be getting a 480p version at most. Play around with bit rates to find an acceptable size file.